# How big participants consume liquidity

Tags: limit-order, market-order, liquidity

I’m currently studying order flow, and one thing I see a lot is that big participants or institutional traders don’t use market orders in order not to get slippage, instead they use limit orders meaning they’re liquidity providers.

But I also see that they take liquidity too which I found contradictory…

My hypothesis is that it’s because of how they put limit orders but I’m not sure.
I think they put limit orders in a way that the orders get paired with other party's limit orders right away, which seems just like market orders but this way they wouldn’t get unexpected slippage.

For instance, now the security is traded at $400, and one big participant wants to buy 300 shares of it and he condones having a slippage of up to $405, so he puts limit buy orders of 300 shares at $405, which would get paired with the first available limit sell orders at $400 and up to $405, and he won’t have unexpected slippage even if there’re not enough sell limit orders at this range, instead, a part of his orders would just be left unfilled.

I think it makes sense but I’m not sure if it’s true.
Can someone explain how they put limit orders??

Answer (score 1):

In order to provide liquidity, you have to put in an order with a higher bid or a lower ask than NBBO.  So if you place a buy order for $405 when share price is $400, that's a taker not a maker.

If one places a buy order for $405 when share price is $400, effectively, that's a market order with an upside limit.  The fill will include all volume available at/below $405 (which you explained in your next to last paragraph).

Comment: Thanks for answering, do you think it is how big participants put their limit orders? I read an article about iceberg orders they use which they split their limit orders into small chunks, but how they put each limit order sounded just like how I explained above… is it true?

Comment: An Iceberg Order displays only a portion of the total order size.  As shares are filled at the order's price, the order is replenished.  That continues until either the order is filled or the market's price moves away from the order's price.

Comment: Thanks, do they put that potion of their total order size just to get filled right away in the price range they condone like how I explained above?

Comment: One thing I really wanna know is if they really “consume(or take)” liquidity…

Comment: I don't know the inner workings of institutional trading so I can't tell you what kind of orders they are using.  Anyone who trades at current market prices (NBBO) is taking liquidity.  Anyone who places a limit order inside the NBBO quote is providing liquidity.

Comment: Thanks, I just found it really contradictory that, they use limit orders meaning they’re liquidity providers because limit orders itself is liquidity, and the idea that they can’t get their limit orders filled when they don’t have enough liquidity of the other party, is common….